# Define basic inductive types in coq

Tags: coq

Very basic question about coq. How do I define the following two inductive types?

Type 1 containing:
o fo, ffo, fffo...
k, sk, ssk, sssk...
Note that the f here could alternatively be characterized as the natural number index for o.

Type 2 containing the same but now we can also have terms like fsffsk and sfsfso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your first type correctly, you can represent it by combining simpler types defined in the Coq standard library:

```
Definition t1 : Type := nat + nat.
```

The `+` operator on types is the disjoint union of two types.  The idea is that the element `inl n`, which is injected on the left of the union, represents the string `fff...o`, with `n` occurrences of `f`, whereas the element `inr n`, which is injected on the right of the union, represents the string `sss...k`, with `n` occurrences of `s`.

I do not understand the patterns on the second type. Did you really mean to write `fsffsk` instead of `fsfsfsk`?

Comment: Azeveedo De Amorim Thank you. I want to define the possible strings as found in some formal system as type. So characters v_1,v_2,... f,0, ^,V,->,<->,E, \Forall concatenated in any order.

Answer (score 1):

Do you actually need to base type2's definition on type1 ? Because actually just a simple definition :

```
Inductive type2 : Type :=
| o : type2
| k : type2
| f : type2 -> type2
| s : type2 -> type2
.
```

And then define examples like :

```
Definition typeExample : type2 := f (s (f (s (s (f (s (k))))))).
```